# Undefined object while populating dropdownlist using JSON in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

i have some trouble while making two dropdownlist:

- Area: All Areas
- City: City that belong to the selected value of the Area

everything is fine till City read the items from JSON. All of the items in dropdown City are **Undefined**.

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AreaList').change(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem == "" || selectedItem == 0) {
                //Do nothing
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=Url.Content("~/") %>Administration/GetDropDownCity',
                    data: { item: $("#AreaList> option:selected").attr("value") },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    traditional: true,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = "";
                $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                    items += "<option value='" + data.value + "'>" + data.description + "</option>";
                });
                $("#CityList").html(items);
                $("#CityList").removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

The Json does exist, I check on the Firebug and listed as below:

```
"[{\"value\":\"107\",\"description\":\"KOTA DEPOK\"},{\"value\":\"141\",\"description\":\"KOTA JAKARTA SELATAN\"}]"
```

any idea to solve this problem?

### Edit

The problem is solved: I use **jQuery.parseJSON()** to read JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think a variable is in conflict here

```
$.each(data, function (i, data) {
                    items += "<option value='" + data.value + "'>" + data.description + "</option>";
                });
```

in enumerator change `data` to `val` for instance like

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
                    items += "<option value='" + val.value + "'>" + val.description + "</option>";
                });
```

**Edit:** also try alerting `data[0].value` or `data[0].description` to make sure that json string is parsed correctly on client side, otherwise you may have to call `$.parseJson` on returned data.

**Edit 2:** one thing you can try is to use for loop

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
   items += "<option value='" + data[i].value + "'>" + data[i].description + "</option>";
}
```

Comment: I'd used alert(data.value) to ensure the data can be viewed. and the result is Undefined same as on the dropdown list

Comment: have u tried changing variable name from `data` to `val` or something else?